# How to direct connect two virtual machine's NICs just like wired on vmware player?

Tags: vmware

I have two virtual machine on vmware player both, each have a NIC card. I want to direct connect VM1's NIC to VM2's NIC, not bridge, not NAT, not Host-only, just direct connect like connect through wire.

Is is possible? How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an undefined "Custom" virtual network. Address one VM as 192.168.10.1 and the other as 192.168.10.2. With no gateway or NAT it's essentially a two-port hub. I believe that's as close as you'll get to a crossover.